# Fill curved object with color

Tags: opengl

I am new to OpenGL.
I want to draw an object which has 4 vertices. It is like a quad object, but for bottom side I need to draw an arc. Other sides are connected with straight lines. I want to fill the object.

Can anybody guide me to do this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Triangulate your shape and render those triangles any way you prefer (immediate mode / VBO / VAO).

[image: Triangulation of the arc]

1. Convert your arc shape into segments. Number of vertices depends on detalization/smoothness you want to achieve.
2. Triangulate the shape. With simple shapes, like this one, you can do it manually in code (draw it on paper like I did and write down vertices indexes that form triangles). With more complicated shapes you could use a triangulation algorithms (available on Net). When shapes are even more complicated (i.e. animal outline) - you might need to use special 2D/3D modelling software just to make them, and it will do triangulation in there.
3. Render the triangles.

Comment: Thank You very much.It is easy to understand with the diagram and explanation you have given to me.Thanks for the help.